# RVM and GEM_PATH

Tags: path, rubygems, rvm

I have used the same script to setup ruby and gems via rvm for two users on the same machine. I have confirmed with rvm --version that I'm using the same version and things seem to be installing identically.

However, on one my $GEM_PATH is being set properly, on the other both $GEM_PATH and $GEM_HOME are both blank - I have confirmed this both by echo $GEM_PATH and within a ruby script reading ENV['GEM_PATH']

Is RVM meant to set $GEM_PATH? If so, any ideas why it hasn't for me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure both machines are running the same set of ruby and gems?
If the first is running version a of ruby and version b of gems and the second one is running the system versions (very likely on OS X) then the second machine may have different gem paths.

Make sure to do

```
rvm use _version_you_want_
```

in both machines!